# Run script on first boot

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, boot

I want to create a script that will run only on first boot, and never again. I am working on a VM that will be converted on a template so I want to make sure I can create a script that can run automatically when the server boots.

I have some clues that I can put a script under /etc/init.d/firstboot for example, and use chkconfig to do it on rhel (which seems not available on Ubuntu), but I need to do it on Ubuntu 14 and 16, any ideas? -- can I assume that if I put a script under /etc/init.d it will run at boot?

I've been googling but I see many different things. For example I saw something similar for rhel:

```
/etc/init.d/yourscript:
#!/bin/bash
# chkconfig: 2345 9 20
# description: long description

case "$1" in
  start)
    Do your thing !!!
    chkconfig yourscript off
  ;;
  stop|status|restart|reload|force-reload)
    # do nothing
  ;;
esac
```

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could start your script with systemd. Write a systemd unit like:

```
[Unit]
Description=yourscript
ConditionPathExists=/path/to/some/file

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/yourscript

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After enabling this unit it should only start if the file in `ConditionPathExists` exists. You could write your script to remove that file after running. Check [systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) there are more such checks, for example `ConditionFileNotEmpty` or `ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty` which can also be handy.

Comment: but this would not work on Ubuntu 14 right? can I write then a script that deletes itself and put it at the end of `/etc/rc.local` ? would this work for both 14 and 16?

Comment: Well, I would not write a script which deletes itself, seems hack-ish and tricky to evaluate. You could do it the same way: let the script create a file and check the presence of that file before executing. `systemd` seems fully supported on Ubuntu 15.04 but available on older versions. Before `systemd` Ubuntu used `upstart`. Look into the `upstart` documentation on how to run a script there.

Comment: That's why chmod -x $0 is the best solution that I suggested.

Comment: @Marco I did not say otherwise and was not the one who downvoted you. I just provided another solution (with `systemd`).

Comment: @duenni: LOL, np mate! :)

Answer (score -1):

It won't run at boot just because it's in /etc/init.d/.

The script can be in /etc/init.d, but you will have to `initctl reload-configuration` or you may put the script where you want and `echo "/path/to/yourscript start &" >> /etc/rc.local`.

Then, just add `chmod -x $0` at the end of the start section and it will never execute again.

Or if you prefer the script to be deleted instead, use `rm $0`. If you opted for initctl way, use `rm $0 && initctl reload-configuration` to disable instead.